# lucene documents order change after number of commits

Tags: sorting, indexing, lucene

I am facing a problem in ordering of the lucene documents while searching from an index. I need to get the documents in the order of last in fast out, from the last indexed to the first indexed documents. I could see the order was maintained till nine commits to an index. But the order get changed from 10th commit on wards. Noticed that all the document id numbers getting changed and the insertion order not maintained, old documents number all are renumbered to different numbers.

Any solution to maintain the order of insertion even after many commit to the index.

Till nine commits the file structure looks like - no order issue found:

[image]

After the tenth commit, the structure gets changed and order of the docs also getting changed

[image]

Comment: so you order your query results by docid?

Comment: Actually We do not use sorting while querying. I thought it maintains the order of the insertion.

Comment: no it does not, i will add an example to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use docId as ordering reference. This is a lucene internal id and may change depending on indexing operations by lucene.

As an example: if you update a document with docId 1, lucene does a delete and insert internally. this could lead to another docId.

to achieve ordering / sorting by query input you should add a dedicated field to your index. See [Field Javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html). There are several fields for this purpose:

- SortedDocValuesField: byte[] indexed column-wise for sorting/faceting
- SortedSetDocValuesField: SortedSet indexed column-wise for
  sorting/faceting
- NumericDocValuesField: long indexed column-wise for sorting/faceting
- SortedNumericDocValuesField: SortedSet indexed column-wise for
  sorting/faceting

**Important:** this fields are used for scoring / sorting / faceting only. If you wanna have this value also in a query result you have to add an additional StoredField for this value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Make sense. I will check and let you know any clarification.

Comment: Tried with separate stand alone code and it worked. This to incorporate to our main application  requires other changes and dependencies. So checking on that changes. Thanks a lot for your support & instructions.

Comment: alright. can you mark as anwered or add an additional answer just for the others with the same problem ;)